# How Do I Properly Parse String For Substring?

Tags: iphone, string, exception, range, substring

I'm a noob to iphone development and I am trying to parse a substring for a string.  The substring I am parsing for will vary in length each time it is parsed, so I am using substring with range to indicate the two characters the substring will always be between.  The problem is that when i get an exception that says Exception - -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
NSString * storyLink = @"http://link.brightcove.com/services/link/bcpid1683318714001/bclid1644543007001/bctid2212677853001?src=mrss"//<--Parsing the numbers between "bctid" & "?src"
NSRange start = [storyLink rangeOfString:@"d" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSRange end = [storyLink rangeOfString:@"?" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *clipid = [storyLink substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location, end.location)];//<--Exception thrown here
NSLog(@"clipid: %@", clipid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranges are interpreted to be in the form `{ begin, length }`. There's a reason the members of the `NSRange` structure are called `location` and `length` instead of `begin` and `end`. Change your code to

```
NSMakeRange(start.location, end.location - start.location)
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now.  I was approaching this like it was JAVA.